# Code indentation on RichTextEditor in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on my own basic syntax highlight editor in C#. I've already completed the automatic coloring of keywords, functions etc etc. I don't need any other fancy stuff like automatic code indentation.

However, I do wish to have a code minify / maxify button. Nothing fancy. I just want it to automaticly set a newline before any opening bracket and one behind it with either tab characters or changing the [SelectionIndent Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionindent.aspx).

So something like this:

```
test { test { test } test }
```

Becomes:

```
test
{
    test
    {
        test
    }
}
```

And of course the minify button should do the exact opposite, putting everything on 1 line.

I've already tried working with the [Regex.Replace Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx). I didn't quite get it to work, but thinking about that approach, it would cause issues if the opening and closing brackets get mixed up. Anyway, this is what I had untill I gave up and decided to ask you guys for some help:

```
string tabs = "";

private void btnMax_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var count = codeRichTextBox.Text.Count(x => x == '{');
    for(int i=1; i<= count; i++)
    {
        // The idea was to add \t to tabs here on each iteration
    }
    string pattern = "{";
    string replacement = "\n{\n\t";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    string result = rgx.Replace(codeRichTextBox.Text, replacement);

    codeRichTextBox.Text = result;
}
```

Obviously that solution is the wrong approach and isn't going to work. So what should I do instead?

Edit: Although it would be nice, it doesn't have to take into account that part of the string already has code indentation. The maxify button only needs to work on a string that's on a single line.

Comment: Whatever approach you use, be sure you make the code smart enough to ignore any brackets that occur inside strings and comments.

Comment: @RJM Normally I would agree with you, but since this is gonna be an editor for Minecraft command blocks, I'm 100% sure that will never be the case. Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea:  You'll need to parse the text, counting the current nesting level of { and } .

For each { or } found, decide on the proper whitespace-string-before (prefix) and whitespace-string-after (suffix) based on the current nesting level (for example just \n { \n for the first level).

See if the desired prefix is already there.  If not, delete any existing whitespace then add the prefix.  Do the same for the suffix.

Comment: Seems an interesting idea! I'm working on something with it. Will let you know :)

Comment: It took me a couple of hours tinkering around with your idea, but it's working perfectly! Thanks for the point into the right direction!